# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.ArrowAssoc(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object

Tags: java, scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am working with flink and kafka, i got this error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.ArrowAssoc(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at kafka.consumer.FetchRequestAndResponseMetrics.<init>(FetchRequestAndResponseStats.scala:32)
    at kafka.consumer.FetchRequestAndResponseStats.<init>(FetchRequestAndResponseStats.scala:46)
    at kafka.consumer.FetchRequestAndResponseStatsRegistry$$anonfun$2.apply(FetchRequestAndResponseStats.scala:59)
    at kafka.consumer.FetchRequestAndResponseStatsRegistry$$anonfun$2.apply(FetchRequestAndResponseStats.scala:59)
    at kafka.utils.Pool.getAndMaybePut(Pool.scala:61)
    at kafka.consumer.FetchRequestAndResponseStatsRegistry$.getFetchRequestAndResponseStats(FetchRequestAndResponseStats.scala:63)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.<init>(SimpleConsumer.scala:39)
    at kafka.javaapi.consumer.SimpleConsumer.<init>(SimpleConsumer.scala:34)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer.getPartitionsForTopic(FlinkKafkaConsumer.java:695)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer.<init>(FlinkKafkaConsumer.java:281)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer082.<init>(FlinkKafkaConsumer082.java:49)
    at com.inndata.flinkkafka.ReadFromKafka.main(ReadFromKafka.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:505)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:403)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.Client.runBlocking(Client.java:248)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.executeProgramBlocking(CliFrontend.java:866)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:333)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1192)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1243)
```

i am using flink - 1.0.3 version and Kafka- kafka_2.11-0.8.2.1 and scala - 2.11.5, these are the jars i am using in my buildpath :

```
asm-4.0.jar,commons-codec-1.6.jar,commons-exec-1.1.jar,commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar,commons-io-2.4.jar,commons-lang-2.5.jar,commons-logging-1.1.3.jar,commons-logging-api-1.1.jar,curator-test-3.2.0.jar,disruptor-2.10.1.jar,flink-annotations-1.0.3.jar,flink-clients_2.10-1.0.3.jar,flink-clients_2.10-1.0.3-tests.jar,flink-core-1.0.3.jar,flink-dist_2.10-1.0.3.jar,flink-java-1.0.3.jar,flink-optimizer_2.10-1.0.3.jar,flink-python_2.10-1.0.3.jar,flink-runtime_2.10-1.0.3.jar,flink-test-utils_2.10-1.0.3.jar,guava-11.0.2.jar,hadoop-client-2.6.0.jar,hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.6.0.jar,hamcrest-all-1.3.jar,jetty-6.1.26.jar,jetty-util-6.1.26.jar,json-simple-1.1.1.jar,junit-4.11.jar,log4j-1.2.17.jar,logback-classic-1.0.13.jar,logback-core-1.0.13.jar,slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar,slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar,zkclient-0.3.jar,zookeeper-3.4.6.jar,flink-connector-kafka-0.10.2.jar,flink-streaming-java-0.10.2.jar,kafka-clients-0.8.2.1.jar,kafka_2.11-0.8.2.1-test.jar,kafka_2.11-0.8.2.1-sources.jar,kafka_2.11-0.8.2.1-scaladoc.jar,kafka_2.11-0.8.2.1-javadoc.jar,kafka_2.11-0.8.2.1.jar,scala-xml_2.11-1.0.2.jar,scala-parser-combinators_2.11-1.0.2.jar,scala-library-2.11.5.jar,metrics-core-2.2.0.jar
```

I tried searching for this issue, but i can't find relevent jar.Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Most of the NoSuchMethodErrors are due to the fact that at development/compile time you used one of version of jar and runtime you are using another version of jar (which doesn't contain the method with exact syntax you are looking for). Check jar versions between compile time & run time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089852/what-is-the-reason-for-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-scala-predef-arrowassoc-upo

Comment: There are `_2.10` and `_2.11` scala libs in the classpath, those are not compatible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError in Flink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46920543/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-in-flink)

Comment: @kosa How do I check that?

Answer (score 4):

There are a few jars that might be the cause of the issue. `scala-library-2.11.5.jar` suggests you are using Scala 2.11, this seems consistent with `kafka_2.11-0.8.2.1.jar`.

But, also in your CP, I see `flink-clients_2.10-1.0.3.jar` and `flink-runtime_2.10-1.0.3.jar` among others. These are scala libraries that were compiled against Scala 2.10. That's the problem.

Binaries in Scala are not compatible across major versions. You need to find the 2.11 version of these jars if they exist or compile them to 2.11 yourself.

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate to Scala folder under your project folder,  e.g. `src -> test -> scala`
2. Right click on Scala directory and choose mark directory as `Test Sources Root`
3. Now mark mark `src` directory as `Sources Root`

Answer (score 0):

Facing same issue in my codebase as well when trying to trigger a simulation using Runner class, but when triggering using the below maven command this looks fine,

```
mvn gatling:test -Dgatling.simulationClass=simulations.simulationClassName
```

**this is just because of version mismatch**

things to check before running it using Runner class(Worked for me)

1. Check if java is correctly configured and reflect the version
   (1.8.0_251 in my case)
2. Check if maven is correctly set (3.6.3 pointing to the same java
   version as above)
3. If you're using IntelliJ, make sure you've added scala SDK in global
   libraries(2.12.8 in my case)
4. Once all configured rebuild your project
5. Trigger your simulation using Runner now, should work.