# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.ArrowAssoc(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;

Tags: java, json, scala, apache-spark, classnotfoundexception

I am developing a project with Apache Spark and Scala.

I have used PlayAPI json in order to parse the json string in Scala object.

I am using Scala version 2.11.7 for the project.

Application works completely fine in Eclipse IDE but when I deploy the jar file using maven and try to run the Spark Job I am getting below error for play API.

```
ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.ArrowAssoc(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;  
at play.api.libs.json.jackson.KeyRead.addValue(JacksonJson.scala:104)   
at play.api.libs.json.jackson.JsValueDeserializer$$anonfun$1.apply(JacksonJson.scala:182)   
at play.api.libs.json.jackson.JsValueDeserializer$$anonfun$1.apply(JacksonJson.scala:180)   
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)   
at play.api.libs.json.jackson.JsValueDeserializer.deserialize(JacksonJson.scala:180)    
at play.api.libs.json.jackson.JsValueDeserializer.deserialize(JacksonJson.scala:120)    
at play.api.libs.json.jackson.JsValueDeserializer.deserialize(JacksonJson.scala:115)    
at com.fasterxml.jackson.d
at abind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3038)    
at com.fasterxml.jackson.d
at abind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1652)     
at play.api.libs.json.jackson.JacksonJson$.parseJsValue(JacksonJson.scala:238)  
at play.api.libs.json.Json$.parse(Json.scala:21)    
at org.first.Hello$$anonfun$3.apply(Hello.scala:20)     
at org.first.Hello$$anonfun$3.apply(Hello.scala:19)
```

I am using the same version of Scala compiler in IDE and system.

Can you guys please help me with the issue?

Comment: It seems a build issue: your final build is missing some library

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25089852/105224

Comment: I tried every suggestions on the above link but the issue still persists