# How can I access items of of scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray in java?

Tags: java, scalar

My code generate syntax error like following:

The type `scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray<String>` cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required `.class files`.

```
WrappedArray<String> a = xxx;
String item = a.apply(1) ; //this code generate red error mark.
```

Comment: are you using eclipse? If yes possible duplicate please check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547162/eclipse-error-indirectly-referenced-from-required-class-files

Comment: I can build the sources after adding scala-library dependency to the pom.xml, but now a runtime error occurs as followings : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.ArrowAssoc(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;

Comment: I found the solution link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089852/what-is-the-reason-for-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-scala-predef-arrowassoc-upo.

Comment: I think it as scala version mismatching problem